# How do i fix No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: python, django, postgresql

```
already_transferred = Transfer.objects.all().filter(transferred_by=request.user, account_id=id).aggregate(total=Coalesce(Sum('amount'), 0))
```

and the server is giving this error

```
function sum(text) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COALESCE(SUM("API_insidetransfer"."amount"), 0) AS "a...
                        ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

here is my model

```
class Transfer(models.Model):
    transferred_by = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    account_id = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    amount = models.CharField(max_length=120, default=0)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: The `amount` is a `CharField`?

Comment: yes, i have other models where amount is CharField and it works

Comment: of course that works, as long as you fetch or store data, that definitely works. But here you aim to *sum up* the amounts. You can not sum up strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `amount` is a `CharField`. You can not sum charfields. What would be the sum of `'foo'` and `'bar'` for example.

You thus should fix the problem on the model level: make `amount` a `DecimalField` (or an `IntegerField`). For example:

```
class Transfer(models.Model):
    transferred_by = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    account_id = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    amount = modelsDecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try it and will let you know!

Comment: I had the same error  , and tried many fixes and didn't work , only ur replied helped me to figure out the problem .. thanks :)